# Add additional attachments to the PublishTestResults@2 Task

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration

I try using Azure Devops PublishTestResults and want that in my Test Run some additional files will get stored as attachments.

This right here is what i mean:

[image]

Right now it is just adding the xml file with the testrun itsself, but i want to add some files to it.

I tried this:

```
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
    inputs:
      testResultsFiles: |
        $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/outputxunit.xml
      publishRunAttachments: true
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test-results'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

But my test-results folder keeps getting ignored from the attachments.

How can i add it to the attachments?

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs more info on what's there in `test-results`, what and which task creates it, etc. You can try to use [File matching wild cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops) to upload additional files, say, JSON files present in `test-results` as:

```yaml
- task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
    inputs:
      testResultsFiles: |
        $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/outputxunit.xml
        $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test-results/**.json
      publishRunAttachments: true
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

As the documentation of [`testResultFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-test-results-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=junit%2Ctrxattachments%2Cyaml#inputs) states, we need to specify multiple paths using a line-break here. `searchFolder` is traversing all the sub-directories present in `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` using `**/*` pattern.

Comment: i want to add a robot script to the attachment. this is my error with your suggestion:##[warning]Failed to read /home/vagrant/myagent/_work/1/s/test-results/tc-2216.robot. Error : Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1..

Comment: @SebastianG. Please post the current version of your pipeline and the error information from build logs for us to get more info. Thanks!